# (Java) Changing variables in a instance of a class

Tags: java, class, variables, jframe

I've been look at this problem all day, and I can't seem to understand what is happening.  Basically, I have 2 classes, one is a `JFrame` and the other is just a game loop really.  The `JFrame` class is supposed to change some variables depending on what the user is clicking.

However, when clicking on the button, the methods don't change any variables.  The only way I can change a variable in my `JFrame` is by calling a method in it, from my calling class.

Here is a sample of the relevant code.

```
public class CMBBattle {

public void startCombat (object.PlayerVariables p1Char1, object.PlayerVariables p1Char2, object.PlayerVariables p1Char3){
    boolean status;
    int teamMovesLeft = 0;

    Battle battle = new Battle(p1Char1, p1Char2, p1Char3);

    status = battle.combatStatus();
    teamMovesLeft = battle.getMovesLeft();
    while (status == true){
        teamMovesLeft = battle.getMovesLeft();
        if (teamMovesLeft <= 0){
            battle.createBattleOrder();
            battle.doBattle();
        }
        status = battle.combatStatus();
        if(status == true){
            battle.newRound();
        }
    }
  }

  public class Battle extends JFrame implements MouseListener {
     private String currentCharacter;

   private void characterOrders(String userChoice, String playerHit){
    int playerAttacker = 0;
    int abilityUsed = 0;
    int speedOfHit = 0;
    boolean finished = false;

    //TODO Currently nothing is happening with what you actually used, i think this was in the old code. Re-implement
    //TODO At this point I am going to just say everything is a quick attack.  So, it'll take up 1 per attack.
    //TODO Add logic to see if something is over their move limit or not
    speedOfHit = 1;

    if(currentCharacter.equals(Player1.charName)){
        playerAttacker = 1;
        char1Orders[moveUses][0] = figureDamage(abilityUsed);
        char1Orders[moveUses][1] = playerAttacker;
        char1Orders[moveUses][2] = getCharacterID(playerHit);
        if((currentPlayerMoves - speedOfHit) <= 0){
            player1.ordersFinished = true;
            finished = true;
        }
    }
    else if(currentCharacter.equals(player2.charName)){
        playerAttacker = 2;
        char2Orders[moveUses][0] = figureDamage(abilityUsed);
        char2Orders[moveUses][1] = playerAttacker;
        char2Orders[moveUses][2] = getCharacterID(playerHit);
        if((currentPlayerMoves - speedOfHit) <= 0){
            player2.ordersFinished = true;
            finished = true;
        }
    }
    else if(currentCharacter.equals(player3.charName)){
        playerAttacker = 3;
        char3Orders[moveUses][0] = figureDamage(abilityUsed);
        char3Orders[moveUses][1] = playerAttacker;
        char3Orders[moveUses][2] = getCharacterID(playerHit);
        if((currentPlayerMoves - speedOfHit) <= 0){
            player3.ordersFinished = true;
            finished = true;
        }
    }
    moveUses += 1;

    //The following decides if it's time for the next player or not, if this is the last player,
    //then it's time to set it to zero and let the handler do the rest.
    if(finished == true){
        if(player1.ordersFinished == false){
            currentCharacter = player1.charName;
            currentPlayerMoves = player1.moves;
        }
        else if(player2.ordersFinished == false){
            currentCharacter = player2.charName;
                            //THE PROBLEM IS RIGHT HERE, THE LINE ABOVE SHOULD HAVE
                            //CHANGED CURRENTCHARACTER, BUT IT DID NOT
            currentPlayerMoves = player2.Moves;
        }
        else if(player3.ordersFinished == false){
            currentCharacter = player3.charName;
            currentPlayerMoves = player3.moves;
        }
        else {
            currentCharacter = "";
            currentPlayerMoves = 0;
        }
        moveUses = 0;
    }
    else{
        currentPlayerMoves -= 1;
    }

    /*
    if (actualUses != Character.moves){
        //TODO We should add logic so that an unitilized variable isn't used...
        //If they don't do anything, set the rest of their array to zeroe's so we can later say, if zero exclude them from round or don't worry about the shite
    }
    */
}

   public String setCurrent(){
   currentCharacter = "NewPerson";
    }

    @Override
public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
    if(!currentCharacter.equals("")){
        String playerHit = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Who should "                          + currentCharacter + " attack?");
        if(e.getSource() == attackButton){
            characterOrders("Attack", playerHit);
        }
    }
}
```

}

Now if I call `setCurrent` from my `startCombat` method, the variable changes.  However, clicking does not change the variable.  It will run the code fine, however when it gets to the part where it changes it, it will not change it.  I'm sure I'm just missing something, but I can't figure out the rule that I've over looked...

--UPDATE-- I updated the `CharacterOrders` to reflect my actual code as it is right now
Please note that `currentCharacter` is the current `Character` who is issuing orders.

Comment: How do you know that the assignment in CharacterOrders has been executed?  How do you know CharacterOrders has been executed at all?

Comment: how can setCurrent work? it has no paranthesis, the compiler shouldn't allow that. also, is the current character supposed to be the character of the other team that is the target?

Comment: That's my bad, i wrote that on here but that's not a direct copy and paste.  I'll update the information with the actual copy and paste

Comment: Please submit code that compiles and start method and variable names with a lowercase letter, using uppercase makes it difficult to understand your code. We are used to reading code that follows the standard conventions.

Answer (score 0):

shouldn't it be

```
private void CharacterOrders(String userChoice, String PlayerHit)
{
    currentCharacter = PlayerHit;
}
```

Comment: Yes, it is in the actual code.  However, i was trying to just give the general idea of what the code is doing.  The code on my side is working I guess the problem line is that i am unable to change currentCharacter in CharacterOrders.

Comment: then why did you post that it is `currentCharacter = userChoice;`?

Answer (score 0):

Okay, since the code is incomplete and I'm finding it somewhat difficult to follow, I could be totally on the wrong track here.

But...where did `playerHit` come from in your listener for mouseClicked? Where is it being set? I'm not sure, but maybe `playerHit` doesn't correspond to the name of any of the players, and as a result, it's not entering your first set of three `if-else` statements, and so `finished` is never `true`?

If you can post more information, or maybe make the code more informative, we might be able to get more of an idea as to what your problem is. Sorry if this wasn't the solution.

**Not part of solution** but it might make the code a bit cleaner: in your first set of `if-else` statements in `characterOrders`, maybe you could just set some variable to be either `char1Orders`, `char2Orders` or `char3Orders` instead of having to call each one separately? Then operate on the variable instead?

So kinda like

```
if(currentCharacter.equals(Player1.charName)) {
    myVariable = char1Orders;
}
else if(/*...a condition...*/) {
   //...more code
}
//...
myVariable[0] = /*...*/;
//...etc.
```

Comment: I was before in the code, and had to change it to this because of some complications. However the problem really is not any of the actual flow.  It flows how i want, and i can tell this because i'm debugging it in eclipse.  However, when it gets to the part where i'm trying to change the currentCharacter variable, the code doesn't actually change it, however it does run that line of code.

Comment: Ah, the code actually is running? Okay. Hmm...well if the values are all distinct, and they're all different objects then that's somewhat more difficult to figure out. The only thing I can think of at the moment is that they might not be distinct values. Other than that, well...I've got nothing...sorry...=\

Comment: haha it's okay.  I think the problem is either A. I need to re-read about static and non static methods/variables, or B. Since the main class is running in a loop, perhaps that's blocking my jframe from running.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is my lack of understand of threads (which I have now rectified).  Since i was creating my JFrame, and then hoping it would just run concurrently with the code, it was never allowed to execute it's code because technically it was still being created.  So, pay attention to threads is the answer.